# localhost times out when using golang proxy

Tags: http, go, networking, https, proxy

I am trying to run a simple proxy and web app I made with GO on Ubuntu 20.04.5 and the web app (http://localhost:8000) will work on the browser however when I bind it with the proxy port (https://localhost:1111) localhost will load until it times out and fails. The proxy code compiles with no errors and is able to bind onto the correct port.

I have tried changing the ports for both and still get the same result.

Here is the proxy code goproxy.go :

```
package main

import (
        "io"
        "log"
        "net"
)

func main(){ 
        //listen for proxy requests
        listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1111")
        if err != nil { 
                log.Fatalln("unable to bind on port ")
        } else { 
                log.Printf("binded on port")
        }


        for 
        {
                conn, err := listener.Accept()
                if err != nil { 
                        log.Fatalln("unable to accept connection ")
                } else {
                        log.Printf("accepted connection")
                }
                //handling proxy request
                go handleConn(conn)
        }
}
func handleConn(src net.Conn) { 
        //connect to the server
        dst, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8000")
        if err != nil { 
                log.Fatalln("unable to target server ")
        } else {
                log.Printf("connected to target server")
        }

        defer dst.Close()

        //copy the src output to the dst. connection
        go func() { 
                if _,err := io.Copy(dst, src); err != nil { 
                        log.Fatalln(err)
                } else {
                        log.Printf("copied src output to the dst conn")
                }
        }()
        //use the respone for target serve connection to src connection
        if _,err := io.Copy(dst, src); err != nil { 
                        log.Fatalln(err)
        }else {
                log.Printf("using the response for target server connection")
        }

}
```

Web server code goserver.go :

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"

)

func formHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
        if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil { 
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
                return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "POST request is successful\n")
        name := r.FormValue("name")
        address := r.FormValue("address")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Name = %s\n", name)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Address = %s\n", address)
}

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
if r.URL.Path !="/hello"{ 
        http.Error(w, "404 not found", http.StatusFound)
        return
}
if r.Method != "GET" { 
        http.Error(w, "method is not supported", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
}
fmt.Fprintf(w,"hello!")
}

func main(){ 
        fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
        http.Handle("/", fileServer)
        http.HandleFunc("/form", formHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

        fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8000\n")
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000",nil); err !=nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

Running the cURL command with the HTTPS localhost

```
cmps401@WINDOWS-HLFMIEE:~/goprogram$ curl -v https://localhost:1111
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1111...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1111 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

Any help with this is appreciated and this is also my first GO program. let me know if I need to provide any more info.

Comment: I  see in your code two times copying the dst to the src, never copying the src to dst.  Likely a typo since your intend based on the documentation for the first copy was to copy src to dst.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here:

1. Both your `io.Copy()` calls are in the same direction. You need to reverse `src` and `dst` in one of them.
2. Your curl command line is using HTTPS but you code is just plain HTTP.
3. Your curl request is just asking for the root which will invoke file server and probably just return something like "file not found".  Try this curl command line:

```
$ curl http://localhost:1111/hello
```

Comment: BTW I think this is an experiment but if you just want a reverse proxy without the hassle of writing one you can just use the Go std lib `httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy`